Does modern Firefox have a context menu "This Frame"> "Inspect element"?
I am aware that I can see the elements within an iframe in the inspector, but I need to run a javascript snippet in the console against the iframe's contents. That's of course forbidden by the gods of the internet (this is even a set of local html files, not that it makes any difference).
I need to do this between 100 and 180 times (don't have an exact count), and right-clicking "open this frame in a new tab" just so I can then bring up devtools is getting to be a major pain in the ass. Is it possible to enable something in about:config to make this more direct?
Willing to switch to Chrome temporarily if it has this functionality.

Surely you could answer this just by running Firefox and having a look?

Yeh, I can just look. There's not 10 zillion tabs, configuration pages, panels, widgets, checkboxes, strange about:config settings, and other assorted doodads. Should be able to find it at a glance, right?

On the devtools console on the right, there's a miniature paneled screen. Click it to set the context for all devtools panels, including DOM Inspector and the JS console. I created a small HTML file with an embedded YT video, so those are the choices in the screenshot below.


To whom it may concern, this feature is also available in Chrome in the console just to the right of the no-smoking icon (top-left of console, not window). I broke a 14 month streak of no longer using Chrome. Thanks Nanigashi, yours is a big help anyway.
